# Solving the system $3.45e-x+4.65y=13$, $x^{e}+1.65y=4$

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I have this system
\begin{align}
 3.45e-x+4.65y&=13 
\\
 x^{e}+1.65y&=4 
\end{align}
But i can't determine what kind of problem this is to resolve it from mathway.

Comment: this is nonlinear system in two variables, so it seems you need to find the solution for this system.

Comment: @CroCo this system doesn't look simular which i already handle. How i can rid of "e" in this system? Looks like i can somehow get integers (x,y) from sytem. Any docs how to do this?

Comment: You may need to take a look at numerical methods.

Comment: Is $3.45e-x$ supposed to be $3.45e^{-x}?$  It has been both ways in the edits and your original post was not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can guess, this is a non-linear system of equations. It is here trivial to eliminate $y$ so that you are left with a scalar non-linear equation in $x$. Here and in general there is no symbolic solution, the best you can do is to identify intervals with a sign change and use a bracketing numerical method to find root approximations.

Comment: Bracketing methods certainly aren't necessary, pretty much any method works well here as the resulting function in $x$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for $y$ and eliminating it from the system of equations, one is left with

$$\frac1{1.65}x^e+\frac1{4.65}x+C=0$$

where $C=\frac{13-3.45e}{4.65}-\frac4{1.65}$ is constant. Since the RHS is increasing in $x$ over $[0,\infty)$, there is a unique solution and it may be easily estimated as $x\approx1.34486025094$ using methods such as Newton's method.

Substituting this back in for $y$, one finds $y\approx1.0681264393$.